# Primitive of piece-wise function.

Tags: calculus

I need to find a primitive $F$ of $f$ on the interval $(0,\infty)$.

$$f:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$$
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2-2}{x}&\text{for }x \in (0,1)\\  
2\ln x-1 &\text{for }x \in (1,\infty)\end{cases}$$

I calculated the definite integral of $f(x)$ on each interval:
$$F(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2}{2}-2\ln x&\text{for }x \in (0,1)\\  
2x(\ln x-1)-x &\text{for }x \in (1,\infty)\end{cases}$$

How do I find a primitive on $(0,\infty)$? Do I set the definite integral on $(0,1)$ equal to the definite integral on $(1,\infty)$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is can be extended to a continuous function from $(0,\infty)$ into $\mathbb R$ (simply taking $f(1)=-1$), you can take\begin{align}F(x)&=\int_1^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt\\&=\begin{cases}2x\log(x)-3x+3&\text{ if }x\geqslant1\\\frac{x^2}2-2\log(x)-\frac12&\text{ if }x\in(0,1).\end{cases}\end{align}